# Stateful Bean : serlvet takes wrong value while managedBean not

Tags: ejb-3.0, javabeans, managed-bean, stateful-session-bean

I've got a `Stateful Session Bean` which holds my login session, a `JSF Session Bean` and a `Servlet Filter`.

What I ned to do is to stop non logged users from accessing my pages, so I did a filter.

The `doFilter()` its like this :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());
    System.out.println(userManager.isLogged());
    if (userManager.isLogged() || path.equals("/") || path.equals("/index.xhtml") || path.startsWith(ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER) || path.startsWith("/resources/") || path.startsWith("/admin") || path.equals("/admin/login.xhtml")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/error.xhtml").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

where `userManager` is found with :

```
private UserManagerLocal lookupUserManagerLocal() {
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        return (UserManagerLocal) c.lookup("java:global/UNILIFE/UNILIFE-ejb/UserManager!ejb.UserManagerLocal");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
        throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
}
```

Now, `System.out.println(userManager.isLogged());` prints **always** false, while `#{loginBean.logged}` prints true.

Note that `loginBean.logged` is just

```
public boolean isLogged() {
    return userManager.isLogged();
}
```

and, in my Managed Bean, `userManager` is retrieved with

```
@EJB
private UserManagerLocal userManager;
```

Seems like that the servlet does not take the same SFSB as the JSF Managed Bean.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT : new code

servlet

```
UserManagerLocal userManager = lookupUserManagerLocal();
private UserManagerLocal lookupUserManagerLocal() {
    try {
        Context c = new InitialContext();
        UserManagerLocal userM = (UserManagerLocal) c.lookup("java:global/UNILIFE/UNILIFE-ejb/UserManager!ejb.UserManagerLocal");
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        req.setAttribute("userManager", userM);
        return userM;
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "exception caught", ne);
        throw new RuntimeException(ne);
    }
}
```

jsf bean

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    userManager = (UserManagerLocal) req.getSession().getAttribute("userManager");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you lookup the stateful session bean, you're creating a unique instance, so isLogged is presumably returning the default field value.  You need to somehow store the stateful session bean instance in the HttpSession and retrieve that from your filter.  I lack JSF expertise, so I don't know if there's a convenient way to share the stateful session bean instance or if you'll need to manually link the JSF bean to the stateful bean.

Answer (score 0):

Each JNDI lookup will return a new handle to bean. Therefore you are getting the default value while calling method, discarding previous activities. You need to save that reference(HttpSession) for further operations on it, as explained in other post.

Below is sample code to access session in JSF bean.

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

From request, you can get session & then placing in it.

```
session.setAttribute("userManager", userManager);
```

Now in filter, you can retrieve bean from request. Also, modify code accordingly.

Comment: I've tried it, but the servlet is accessed before my bean is created, so `req.getSession().getAttribute("userManager");` returns null and my filter dosen't work at all

Comment: @StepTNT You can then reverse the case. Set it in servlet & fetch in bean.

Comment: ...and now the NPE is thrown by the JSF Managed bean :\

Comment: @StepTNT It seems you aren't getting bean in servlet & setting null, have you verified it.

Comment: @StepTNT But you haven't mentioned any exceptions or output of added code. Also, initialize context with server specific properties & proper JNDI lookup string.

Comment: I wrote it in my previous comment, my JSF Bean throws a NPE when I try to access the SFSB

Comment: @StepTNT As I already mentioned, it might happen servlet is failing to lookup the bean & putting null in session, so code in JSF will have NPE, try debugging further.